# Why use multi AZ deployment for AWS Aurora

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Generally when using AWS RDS, the recommended practice to achieve high availability is to deploy hot replica in different AZ (multi AZ deployment). Also, some read replicas can be brought up to improve read performance.

I've read AWS Aurora documentation, it uses common virtual storage layer, which is replicated on 3 AZ, with two copies in each AZ.

[image]

My question is this: Is there any need to use Amazon multi AZ deployment of Aurora DB cluster, if Aurora itself is capable of healing itself, and has its storage distributed over multi AZs? If it keeps 2 storage copies in each of 3 AZs, then its as reliable as using the multi AZ replica setup for failover. Also, during failover. it automatically creates another instance (if no read replica exist) or switches the primary. I really do not understand any need to create additional requirement of using multi AZ aurora cluster to 'improve' availability.

Is it possible that there's some scenario where availibility would suffer under default Aurora deployment? What happens during loss of an entire AZ which contains the primary Aurora DB node?

Answer (score 3):

If you are only interested in your data not being lost, then a non-multi AZ would probably work fine because, as you said, the data is replicated for you.

But the running instance of Aurora still lives on a physical machine, and that physical machine lives in a single AZ, so if that AZ goes down, while you may not lose any data you won't necessarily have access to it.

A multi-AZ deployment has a physical machine running in more than one AZ, so if one AZ goes down, the database server in the other AZ can still serve your requests.

Comment: Aren't the read replica running on virtual machines? So the primary can be changed to one of those in case the AZ goes down?

Answer (score 3):

The RDS [Multi-AZ feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.MultiAZ.html) is much simpler for Aurora deployments than it is for non-Aurora deployments: An [Aurora Replica](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html) is a Multi-AZ failover target in addition to a read-scaling endpoint, so creating a Multi-AZ Aurora deployment is as simple as deploying an Aurora Replica in a different Availability Zone from the primary instance.

This behavior is different from standard non-Aurora Multi-AZ deployments, which maintain a separate synchronously-replicated 'standby instance' which cannot be used as a read-scaling endpoint, and vice versa (standard RDS Read Replicas cannot be used as Multi-AZ failover targets).

Even though Aurora data is backed up across AZs, having a replica instance already running can still significantly reduce the amount of time it takes to recover from a failure of the primary instance. The typical amount of time Aurora takes to recover from a failover with an Aurora Replica available is **1-2 minutes**, compared to **10 minutes** without a Replica, as described in [Fault Tolerance for an Aurora DB Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Managing.html#Aurora.Managing.FaultTolerance):

> If the primary instance in a DB cluster fails, Aurora automatically fails over to a new primary instance in one of two ways:
>
> - By promoting an existing Aurora Replica to the new primary instance
> - By creating a new primary instance
>
> If the DB cluster has one or more Aurora Replicas, then an Aurora Replica is promoted to the primary instance during a failure event. [...] However, service is typically restored in **less than 120 seconds**, and **often less than 60 seconds**. [...]
>
> If the DB cluster doesn't contain any Aurora Replicas, then the primary instance is recreated during a failure event. [...] Service is restored when the new primary instance is created, which typically takes **less than 10 minutes**.
>
> *Promoting an Aurora Replica to the primary instance is much faster than creating a new primary instance*.

Comment: One of the best explanation and answer I read so far related to this context. Thanks @wjordan
By the way, we still can have a different db instance for the replica right? Say for my production, I can have a db.r4.2xlarge as my primary and have a db.r4.large as replica/multi-AZ standby ?